# Xamarin WebView with caching/service worker?

Tags: xamarin, caching, webview, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a SPA/PWA that I'd like to embed within a WebView in Xamarin. Is there any way to enable caching or handle service worker registration within the WebView?

Thanks.